# Android TableLayout duplication on orientation change

Tags: android, datagrid, fragment, screen-orientation, tablelayout

I'm using TableLayout as a simple DataGrid in my app. The rows are added in code. The problem is; when I change the screen orientation, a new table layout appears on the old one.

The layout file:

```
.
.
.
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dataGrid"
        android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle|end">

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>

</TableLayout>
```

The function called to create test entries. I call it from the `public View onCreateView` of my fragment.

```
private void fillDataGrid(TableLayout dataGrid,Context context)
{

    int columnCount = 5;
    int rowCount = 30;

    List<TextView> fields = new ArrayList<>();

    TableRow row;

    dataGrid.removeAllViews();
    dataGrid.invalidate();
    dataGrid.setStretchAllColumns(true);

    for (int j=0;j<rowCount;j++)
    {
        row = new TableRow(context);

        if (j%2 != 0)
            row.setBackgroundColor(getResources().
                getColor(R.color.highlighted_text_material_light));

        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
        {
            TextView field;
            field = new TextView(context);
            field.setText("field " + i);
            fields.add(field);
            row.addView(field);
        }

        dataGrid.addView(row);
    }
}
```

I'm aware of the redundacy of `List<TextView> fields = new ArrayList<>();`. I'm keeping it to use later.

The sdk versions:

```
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
```

The error occures in a `android.app.Fragment` class.

What I've tried so far:

1. Calling invalidate() and requestLayout() methods for my datagrid TableLayout, parent TableLayout and ScrollView.
2. Attempt to understand how many TableLayouts or ScrollViews are dupplicated. Result was **none** according to my test code.
3. Adding rows in xml and disregarding the fillDataGrid() function, didn't solve the problem. Although the rows are added/manipulated **only** in xml.

What I've learned:

- This is not a render issue. Because when I invoked `scrollView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` I can still scroll the **duplicated** TableLayout.

You can see the screenshots that describe the situation below.

Thank you.

[image: Normal Table Layout]

[image: Error occured]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem. I was using,

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.mainContainer, fragMain.newInstance("",""))
                        .commit();
```

to attach my first fragment to my main activity in 'onCreate()' method. Since the 'onCreate()' is invoked on orientation change, the fragment was added multiple times. The correct code is:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.mainContainer, fragMain.newInstance("",""))
                        .commit();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a memory leak there...anywhere in your code there is a strong reference that keeps the views from being garbage collected...

What is the dataGrid object that you are giving to fillDataGrid() in your Fragment? Maybe here is the flaw in your construct

Comment: 'private static TableLayout dataGrid' was my declaration. I made it a local variable and non-static, but it didn't work. Also I forgot to mention I added the rows manually in xml file and didn't manipulate the TableLayout in code and the error occured.

Comment: well then do an MAT and find out where you hold your references : see here: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html or here: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html